# Get a list of installed languages in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to display a list of installed languages in a `ComboBox` in a `WPF` application. For example, I have English (United States) and English (India) installed. I want to show these both in my `ComboBox`

I am using the `CultureInfo` class for this. Below is a snippet of what I am trying. I am able to get all the cultures. But I need only those cultures which are installed through system settings.

```
var cultureInfos = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
foreach (var culture in cultureInfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
}
```

Comment: You can use "InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages"

Comment: I got the list. But it asks me to reference `System.Windows.Forms` which I am not allowed to..

Comment: are you talking about installed input languages?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the native function [`GetKeyboardLayoutList`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getkeyboardlayoutlist) to get a list of installed input languages.

Here is a sample:

```
IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetInstalledInputLanguages()
{
    // first determine the number of installed languages
    uint size = GetKeyboardLayoutList(0, null);
    IntPtr[] ids = new IntPtr[size];

    // then get the handles list of those languages
    GetKeyboardLayoutList(ids.Length, ids);

    foreach (int id in ids) // note the explicit cast IntPtr -> int
    {
        yield return new CultureInfo(id & 0xFFFF);
    }
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetKeyboardLayoutList(int nBuff, [Out] IntPtr [] lpList);
```